# Can PHP __clone change a function?

Tags: php, object, clone

So I was wondering if PHP's `__clone()` can also change a function. Documentation only talks about properties. I tried something like

```
//functionName is a class method that exists in the class
//defined before the __clone
    public function __clone() {
        $this->functionName(){ 
           echo 'hello ppl';
        }
    }
```

and it failed. I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpobject.php on line 39` referring to the `echo 'hello ppl';` line.

Chances are that `__clone` cannot do this, but I just want to be sure that there is not a hack or something

Thanks

Comment: You are correct, it can't do that. But what are you trying to achieve with your code? why are you needing to replace a function? Clone lets you do a bit of prep work against the cloned objects properties before using it.

Comment: @Scuzzy No particular reason, I am reading a book about php/mysql and I was just wondering if maybe `__clone` can do this...But, come to think of it, if `__clone` can change properties and methods, then its just `extends`...Anyway, I wont be surprised if someone, somewhere can also do this with `__clone`

Comment: You can program `__call` to behave based on a property. And use `__clone` to set the property.

Comment: An object is an instance of a class, and that the class is defined at runtime and can't change, you can extend that class to change functions, but you can't clone an object into a different class.

Comment: Clone is not like `extends`. It's creating a new object of the same class.

Comment: `extends` is for defining a subclass.